# How to change the position of legend in a map?

Tags: matplotlib, legend, geopandas, shapefile, contextily

I've been trying to plot a shapefile over a basemap. My issue here is the placement of the legend. I wanted it to be placed outside (next to) the map.

Specifically, I am plotting the "Ecoregion" column of the shapefile which basically labels each polygon with a colour (I figured this was better than actually putting the names on each polygon). I've tried the following code and receive an error:

```
pip install geopandas
pip install contextily
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
data = gpd.read_file("icemap.shp")
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
ax = data.plot(
    figsize=(12, 10),
    column="Ecoregion",
    cmap="tab10",
    )
map = Basemap(
    llcrnrlon=-50,
    llcrnrlat=30,
    urcrnrlon=70.0,
    urcrnrlat=85.0,
    resolution="i",
    lat_0=39.5,
    lon_0=1,
)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
map.fillcontinents(color="lightgreen")
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(10,90,20),labels=[1,1,1,1])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,30),labels=[1,1,0,1])
plt.title("Map", fontsize=16)
```

The error is -

> WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend.

So I tried adding

```
legend-True
```

in the "ax" parentheses and removed the "ax.legend(...)", but then the legend appears on top of the map as the picture below.

[image]

Does "handle" refer to the column that is plotted? If so, I'm confused as to why I get this error. Or do I need to add another line of code?

I'd be grateful to receive some help in this.
(Attached file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OfOAstBbbxiqSybpl_CQf-o47YgpbY7D/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why not try cartopy in stead of `Basemap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also consider Cartopy, since Basemap has been end-of-life for a long time. The resolution of your vector is also well beyond what's plotted on screen, so you could really increase performance by simplifying it a little.

But you can pass the legend keywords along when plotting the Geodataframe.

```py
ax = data.plot(
    figsize=(10, 8),
    column="Ecoregion",
    cmap="tab10",
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds=dict(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left'),
)
```

[image]